# NullPointerException with getActivity() and not sure how to do intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi I'm a complete beginner at Android development so I don't really know too much of what I'm doing. I keep getting nullpointerexecption and my program crashes whenever getActivity() is called. This includes in toast messages as well as when I try to start another activity with an intent. I'm not entirely sure how to use intents either so if that could be explained that would be great.

Here is the class that has the getActivity() calls as well as intent:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class loginDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.loginw)
                .setItems(R.array.account_types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        if(which==0){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"todo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(which==1){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"todo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(which==2){
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder1=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog,null);
                            builder1.setView(view);
                            builder1.setTitle("Login with Email Address");
                            builder1.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Force Closes. Nullpointer Exception? Probably because of getActivity()
                                    //dialog1.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            builder1.setNeutralButton("Forgot Password",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which){
                                    dialog1.dismiss();
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    builder2.setTitle("Forgot Password");
                                    builder2.setMessage("Enter your Email Address");

                                    builder2.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            //TODO
                                        }
                                    });
                                    builder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            //TODO
                                        }
                                    });
                                    builder2.show();
                                }
                            });
                            builder1.setPositiveButton(R.string.login, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Login complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Force Closes. Nullpointer Exception? Probably because of getActivity()
                                    dialog1.dismiss();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Groups.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                            Dialog dialog1 = builder1.create();
                            dialog1.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Dialog dialog=builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat (note this is only for the intent call because the other getActivity()s are commented out):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
        at com.app.u.loginDialog$1$3.onClick(loginDialog.java:67)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you include the whole stack trace please? :)

Comment: I case of Exceptions you need to study the logcat output & post it also in your questions please

Comment: Make sure that your Groups is OK. If it has an error, in the onCreate, it will show up like what you see above.

Comment: As far as compiling goes, my Groups class should be okay. (It is also very barebones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create the Intent inside the dialogue popup message So you should use like this Or declare inside your dialogue Like this it will help you Definitely...All the best

```
Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();                         
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);     
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call getActivity after the onActivityCreated method has returned in the Overriden dialogfragment class. in ur case loginDialog class. that is the safe place to call getActivity

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {
    Activity mAct; 

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act) {
        super.onAttach(act);
        mAct = act; // use this mAct instead of getActivity() function
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I don't really understand what you mean. As I said early, I don't really know what I'm doing. I'm getting nullpointerexceptions when I create the intent as well as where ever there is a toast message.(both of these lines have called getActivity). I'm also not exactly sure what getActivity does, just that I've seen tutorials where they used it similarly to how I'm trying to use it.

Comment: override the onAttached(Activity act) function, store this act in a member variable in ur class and use that, then u ll b sure edited answer pls check

Comment: I don't have an AnAttach function. Also when I create it, it needs a return statement.

Comment: sorry wrongly copied code http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity) this is the link to function u need to  override

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getApplicationContext()` instead

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Groups.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And remember to declare your new activity in your AndroidManifest file!

```
<activity android:name=".Groups"/>
```

Comment: When I try getApplicationContext in AndroidStudio I get Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext() as an error.